# Detect Current Page

Tags: html, tumblr

Is there a code snippet that can detect the current user's page and then add `<a class="active">` to an item in a `ul` (my menu). I am making a tumblr theme and they do not allow PHP (I usually add `<?php if ( $current == "home" ) { echo "class='active'" } ?>` in my menu and `$current = "home"` on my pages) and they do not have a standard (such as current_page_item) so I need to do this with javascript (or jQuery) only.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with HTML only but should be straight forward with JQuery, and just a bit harder with javascript only.

Here is a solution relying on JQuery and [URL parser plugin:](http://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) assuming you have the information you need in the file name (e.g: page1.html refered by id="page1")

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var pathname = window.location.pathname;
   var page = jQuery.url.attr('file').replace(".html", "");
   $('#' + page).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not that great with jQuery.  How do I get that to detect my pages?

Comment: You need to download jQuery and URL plugin and reference them in your HTML header like this:


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.url.js" /> then the code I gave you should detect the current page.

Comment: Will it detect it as-is or do any changes need to be made?

Comment: attr('file') will detect the filename in the URL, I don't know if it's suitable in your case. You may have to rework the script. Check the documentation of the URL parser plugin and try it.